# Counter-example of Cavalieri's principle

Tags: calculus

Suppose $S$ is a given solid and $L$ a given line. If a plane $F$ is perpendicular to $L$, the intersection $F\cap S$ is called cross section perpendicular to $L$. If every cross-section perpendicular to $L$ is a measurable set in its own plane, we call $S$ a *Cavalieri solid*. Cavalieri's principle assigns equal volumes to two Cavalieri solids, $S$ and $T$, if  $a(F\cap S) = a(F \cap T)$ for every plane $F$ perpendicular to a given line $L$.

*Doubts*

1. Can this principle be stated in simpler terms?
2. Are there any example of solids which are not *Cavalieri solids*
3. Definition given in Wikipedia-

   > Suppose two regions in three-space (solids) are included between two parallel planes. If every plane parallel to these two planes intersects both regions in cross-sections of equal area, then the two regions have equal volumes.

   How this is equivalent to the above definition?

Comment: As far as (1) goes, I don't think there is a simpler formulation: after all, it's exactly the same statement it has in elementary solid geometry.

Comment: I think this is somewhat similar to integration to find out volume

Comment: For 2 consider the cartesian product of a nonmeasureable plane set with the unit interval.

Comment: I think your first definition need $a(F \cap T)$ rather than $a(S \cap T)$.

Comment: If you have two parallel planes as in the Wikipedia definition, there is a line $L$ perpendicular to both those planes, and every plane $F$ perpendicular to $L$ is parallel to those two planes. So the cross-sections in "every plane" in Wikipedia are the same as the "every cross-section" in the first definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your first $5$ lines and the Wikipedia text say exactly the same thing, and it cannot be said in simpler terms.

If you accept the existence of nonmeasurable sets then there will also be noncavalieri solids.

Now Cavalieri's principle is a consequence of Fubini's theorem (or similar statements) in the special case where $f(x,y,z)\equiv1$: For a compact solid $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ one defines
$$ S':=\bigl\{z\in \mathbb R \bigm|\exists\> (x,y,z)\in S\bigr\},\qquad S_z:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigm| (x,y,z)\in S\bigr\}\quad(z\in S')\ .$$
Hence $S'$ is the projection of $S$ onto the $z$-axis, and for each $z\in S'$ we consider the shape $S_z$ in $(x,y)$-space ${\mathbb R}^2$, created by intersecting $S$ with the horizontal plane  at level $z$. Then
$${\rm vol}(S):=\int_S 1\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)=\int_{S'}\left(\int_{S_z}{\rm d}(x,y)\right)\>{\rm d}(z)=\int_{S'}{\rm area}(S_z)\>{\rm d}(z)\ .$$